# Why is my Variable set to 0?

Tags: java, parameters

```
import java.lang.Math;
public class NewtonIteration {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print(rootNofX(2,9));
    }

    // computes x^n
    public static double power(double x, int n) {
        if (n==0) {
            return 1;
        }       
        double Ergebnis = 1;
        for (int i=0; i<=Math.abs(n)-1; i++) {
            Ergebnis *= x;
        }
        if (n<0) {
            Ergebnis = 1/Ergebnis;
        }

        return Ergebnis;
    }

    // computes x^(1/n)
    public static double rootNofX(int n, double x) {
        return power(x, 1/n);
    }
}
```

Whenever power(x,1/n) is called, n is reset to 0. But isn't n a parameter given to rootNofX with the value 2?

Comment: After you solve the rounding of 1/n to 0, how do you expect your loop to work? You example is trying to find the square root of 9. How did you think this code was going to loop 1/2 a time and semi-multiply 1 * 9 to get 3? You are going to need a different algorithm for performing powers between 0 and 1.

Comment: FYI: x^(1/2) != 1/(x^2)

Please re-learn your laws on exponentiation and logarithms.

 -- Jakob Krainz, Lehrstuhl 2 Informatik, Univ. Erlangen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
// computes x^(1/n)
    public static double rootNofX(int n, double x) {
        return power(x, 1.0/n);
    }
```

Because `1` is an `int` and `n` is an `int` so `1/n` is an integer division which return 0 when n is not 1 and throw error when n is 0.

`1.0` is a double so it make `1.0/n` a double division that you want.

Comment: You also have to change the parameter `n` of the method `power` to `double`, else it still won't work.

Comment: @hjhill: You do not need to. Try it. Cheer! :-D

Answer (score 1):

1/n is going to be a fraction, usually, but in the declaration of power you declare n to be integer. That's going to knock off the decimal places every time!

Answer (score 1):

It's because power is defined with "n" as an int so 1/n will always be less than 1 which will be zero when stored as an int. Update "int n" to "double n". Example below:

```
public static double power(double x, double n) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using integers, so 1 / 2 = 0.5 which as an integer is 0. Change the prototypes to `rootNofx(double n, double x)` and `power(double x, double n)`.

Also, since `rootNofx` uses `power`, in my opinion, it would be better to have the parameters ordered the same way, to avoid confusion.

Comment: 2/1 is 0.5? This must be the new math I'm having so much trouble with! :)

Comment: LOL! Sorry about that, I meant 1 / 2 :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are passing 1/2 from rootNofX into an int, so it becomes zero.

Answer (score 0):

There is a big difference between `1/n` and `1.0/n`

Consider what declaring `n` to be an `int` really means...